# Methods and Strings

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming. My homework problem states that to Write a program that calls a method to print the number of vowels in a sentence (use ‘nextLine()’to read a sentence instead of a single word).  Print the number of occurrences of each vowel (ie: the number of ‘a’s, the number of ‘e’s, etc.) Here is my program so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a string");
  String str = in.nextLine();


  System.out.println("The number a vowels in the sentence are" + vowel(str));
}

  public static String vowel(str)//I'm having trouble here
{
    int len = str.length(); // Here
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
       char str2 = str.charAt(i);//Here
       if (str2 == 'a')
       count++;    
    }
       return str2; // And finally here
 }
```

Comment: Ok, What's the problem?

Comment: I did do it and I have been working on it and I can't figure it out

Comment: Hint: when you're having a problem, the problem comes with the error message. The first thing you should do is read it. And if you don't understand it, post it.

Comment: The compiler will tell you if your "vowel" method's signature is weird (Java is a strongly typed language so you need to specify that the parameter str is a String)

Answer (score 10):

The problem is with your method declaration. You need to declare the type of your `str` parameter, like this:

```
public static String vowel(String str)
```

Additionally, you're only declaring `str2` within your loop - so you can't use it for the return statement (which is outside the loop). Given that you're trying to return a *count* of vowels, you should change the return type to `int` anyway... and then return `count`, not `str2`:

```
public static int vowel(String str) {
    ... code as before apart from last line...
    return count;
}
```

Comment: @DragonAge99: I've edited my answer to include this anyway, but you should be able to come up with it for yourself - what do you have a `count` variable for, and what's meant to be the result of your method?

Answer (score 0):

Also, use an array to stock the occurence of voyels, to handle the result easier.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return str2 after the for-loop, because you declared it inside, and it is invalid outside. Also it has a different data type than the method (String vs char).